# Code prints table in R script, but returns NULL error in RMarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, gt

This is my code:

````
```{r}
library (gt)
library(tidyverse)
library(measurements)
library(lubridate)
library(readxl)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
```

```{r}
solar_data <- read_excel("SolarRadiationAthens.xlsx")
```

```{r}
panel_size <- 32 # in square meters
efficiency <- 0.2 # 20% efficiency
```

```{r}
solar_data <- solar_data %>%
  mutate(day_energy = SolarWatt * panel_size * efficiency / 1000) %>%
  group_by(month = month(Timestamp)) %>%
  summarise(avg_energy = mean(day_energy))
```

```{r}
solar_table <- gt(solar_data) %>%
  tab_header(title = "Average Daily Electricity Generated by Month") %>%
  cols_label(month = "Month", avg_energy = "Electricity Generated (kWh)") %>%
  fmt_number(columns = c(avg_energy), decimals = 2)
```

```{r}
print(solar_table)
```
````

In RMarkdown, the print function returns a NULL error. When saved as PDF, it results in 10 pages of ## text, like below:

[image]

The same code works just fine in R script. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you use `print()` to render your table. To fix that render your table directly without saving it as a variable or use `as_latex()` when you render to PDF.

Using a minimal reproducible example based on mtcars.

First, let's reproduce your issue:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
date: "2023-05-05"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r}
library(gt)

solar_table <- gt(mtcars) %>%
  tab_header(title = "Average Daily Electricity Generated by Month")

print(solar_table)
```
````

[image]

Second, using `as_latex` instead of `print()`:

````
```{r}
library(gt)

solar_table <- gt(mtcars) %>%
  tab_header(title = "Average Daily Electricity Generated by Month")

as_latex(solar_table)
```
````

[image]